# Google Analytics 360 Journey Entry

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

I am putting a Google Analytics 360 Data Extension as an entry source for a journey on SFMC. It works fine, but when I try to filter by email address it doesn't work. Does anyone know about the mapping with email addresses when using GA360. Has anyone else had this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will be helpful: [image] 
Since GA360 only passes the IDs of the subscribers, my best guess is that it matches the emails addresses with the All Subscribers list or the root Data Extension in your contact model?

I would check the contact model, and if needed, create an automation that queries either All Subscribers list or the root DE and replicates all IDs and email addresses to another Data Extension, which you could then link in Data Designer to your GA360 DE.

Comment: Thanks @codeRage very helpful!

Comment: helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @zuzannamj thanks a TON for sharing the illustrative diagram, very helpful to understand how the Intergration works.

Comment: @zuzannamj, does this mean that when using Google Analytics 360 Audience as the Entry source - we don't "risk" getting new contacts? (Because only existing Marketing Cloud contacts will flow back?) I say risk - because new contacts will have to have SubscriberKeys generated which will not match their ContactId from MC Connect.

Comment: hmmm.... @zuzannamj, also when/how is the sfmc_id passed to GA? is it appended to urls in emails on send time? or is it a cookie dropped sometime between the click and arriving to the tracked web-page? or both? The difference is huge. 
If it's only passed in the URL, the Audiences created are only Audiences from SPECIFIC communications (or maybe all starting the integration date?). 
Do we have control over these somewhere in MC?

Comment: Found an answer to my second question here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_gai_faq18.htm&type=5; indeed it is appended to a url, and then it is added to a Cookie with a GA-generated ClientID.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_gai_faq17.htm&type=5

This answers the first question also - only contacts who clicked a specific link which contains the sfmc_id will be tracked and usable back in MC. So no new contacts.

Can anyone confirm the above?